# C++ / CLI linker error because of SHAssocEnumHandlers function

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, clr

To reproduce the issue,

1. Create a project > VC++ > CLR > Class library, name the project "ClassLibrary2" and use below two files as is.

   // ClassLibrary2.h

   ```
    #pragma once

    #include <msclr\marshal.h>
    #include <ShObjIdl.h>

    using namespace System;

   namespace ClassLibrary2 {

   public ref class Class1
     {         
       public :    void ClassLibrary2::Class1::GetAllOpenWithProgs(String^ ext);
     };
   }
   ```

   // ClassLibrary2.cpp

   ```
   // This is the main DLL file.

   #include "stdafx.h"

   #include "ClassLibrary2.h"

   void ClassLibrary2::Class1::GetAllOpenWithProgs(String^ ext)
   {
       msclr::interop::marshal_context ^ context = gcnew msclr::interop::marshal_context();
       PCWSTR pszStr = context->marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(ext);

       IEnumAssocHandlers *pEnumHandlers = NULL;

       /* below line is producing problems */
       SHAssocEnumHandlers(pszStr, ASSOC_FILTER_RECOMMENDED, &pEnumHandlers);
   }
   ```

Now, if I build the project, I get following errors :

> Error 2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0000A2) "extern "C" long
>   __cdecl SHAssocEnumHandlers(wchar_t const *,enum ASSOC_FILTER,struct IEnumAssocHandlers * *)"
>   (?SHAssocEnumHandlers@@$$J0YAJPEB_WW4ASSOC_FILTER@@PEAPEAUIEnumAssocHandlers@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __clrcall
>   ClassLibrary2::Class1::GetAllOpenWithProgs(class System::String ^)"
>   (?GetAllOpenWithProgs@Class1@ClassLibrary2@@$$FQE$AAMXPE$AAVString@System@@@Z)    C:\Users\Anjum\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.obj ClassLibrary2
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long
>   __cdecl SHAssocEnumHandlers(wchar_t const *,enum ASSOC_FILTER,struct IEnumAssocHandlers * *)"
>   (?SHAssocEnumHandlers@@$$J0YAJPEB_WW4ASSOC_FILTER@@PEAPEAUIEnumAssocHandlers@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __clrcall
>   ClassLibrary2::Class1::GetAllOpenWithProgs(class System::String ^)"
>   (?GetAllOpenWithProgs@Class1@ClassLibrary2@@$$FQE$AAMXPE$AAVString@System@@@Z)    C:\Users\Anjum\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.obj ClassLibrary2

How to remove those linker errors ?

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting.  Add shell32.lib

Comment: @HansPassant Trillion thanks. Request you to take a look at this question too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406122/shassocenumhandlers-c-sharp-version-not-working